# XCode - IPhone Development Teams

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

I have paid for IPhone dev license I have everything.
But still when I want to "Add device to Provisioning portal" so that I can test the app on my own IPhone i get the following message:

The indicated user is not on any iPhone Development Teams

Any idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you download and install the team provisioning license from iTunes connect? It should be on your keychain.

Comment: Did you mean to say "download and install the Team Provisioning Profile from the Apple Developer Website"? The references to "license" and iTunesConnect here are confusing, although you do need to fill out the developer contract for the App Store that you  signed up for to develop for (iOS or Mac) before XCode will recognize your provisioning profile, which you do in iTunesConnect.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow through the guide lines given on [APPLE](http://developer.apple.com).

Try login to iOS dev center, and move to iOS provisioning portal.

Then go to Distribution tab. Follow guide line step by step.

Comment: Sorry but I can't see anywhere Distribution?!?!?