# "iPod Developer Teams"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ipad, iphone-developer-program

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Test iOS app on device without apple developer program or jailbreak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak)
>   [XCode - IPhone Development Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957381/xcode-iphone-development-teams)

I cannot compile my iPad app to an iPad (I can only use the simulator). When I try to authorize my iPad for development, I log in with my Apple ID and then get the message, "the indicated user is not on any iphone development teams." I'm having trouble figuring out just what team I am supposed to belong to. Is it talking about the signing up for a full-fledged developer account? Is it really the case that I cannot even test an app on my own iPad without paying? Or is it referring to something else?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957381/xcode-iphone-development-teams?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's really the case that you can't test your app on your own iPad without paying.

Answer (score 0):

Without jailbreaking your device, you'll need to sign up for a [paid] developer subscription.

See also: [Test iOS app on device without apple developer program or jailbreak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak)